# Assigning ID to a widget using GQuery

Tags: gwt, gquery, gwtquery

I need to wrap a widget with an ID, so I used GQuery to do that, like so:

```
GQuery g = $(signupButton);
g.id("signupButton");
```

Now I need to get the instance of the actual Button or Widget using the GQuery object, is that possible?

Will the `g.get(0)` return the wrapped instance of that Button/Widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the widget() method

```
Button b = g.widget();

//later if you want to query your button via its id
Button b = $("#signupButton").widget()
```

Julien